# spring-boot war file deployment

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, war

I tried several solutions to migrate my springboot application to .war. But if I upload the war file at a tomcat server (localhost) I get a HTTP Error 404. I work in Intelliji (Jdk19), with maven and hibernate.

Application:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String start()
    {
        return "Hello User, have a nice day.";
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello()
    {
        return "Hello User, have a nice day.";
    }

}
```

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.19</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

ServletInitalizer:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

As I already mentioned I tried several solutions

Comment: Can you please share the tomcat location where you uploaded war file

Comment: @RohitAgarwal the location is the localhost:8080. I uploaded my war file via web browser.

Comment: What do you mean uploaded war file via web browser?

Comment: I found the Failure! My IDE started a tomcat and the xampp. That was the problem! Now, everything works!